# Convert HTML to CSV or XLS for SSIS Flat File Upload

Tags: python, html, excel, csv, ssis

I have a folder with 1000 html files (daily add of 20-30). Each html file has 4 tables in it. I would like to convert the html file to a format such as excel/csv or comma limited txt file which I can then upload to SQL Server using SSIS flat file upload package.

There are transformations required in the table, like adding columns and resorting columns but I feel that can be taken care of once conversion is done. I've been struggling with **setting up a recurring conversion process for HTML to XLS/CSV/TXT**

I don't think I can upload HTML directly using SSIS, hence converting.

Can anyone please help with how this entire data ingestion may be possible?

I've searched online and on stackoverflow and using **python seems the best option here but I'm not fairly good at it** and seeing if anyone can help with a **template code** for that **or** **alternate direction** completely?

I'm going to have to **automate this at some point** as the volume of new files increase so I have been trying to keep that in mind with any solution I come up now.

Comment: you'll just need to dive in I'm afraid, I'd look at the Beautiful Soup package for dealing with html, `pandas` also has a `pandas.read_html` [method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) which may work if your tables are fairly well structured.

Comment: Python is great, love it to death. Directly integrating with SSIS is a bit fiddly. Instead, envision that you'll have a preprocessor step. Python consumes input html file and emits a CSV. You'll then have a follow up process in SSIS that is responsible for importing CSV into the database.

Comment: @billinkc I missed SSIS and jumped straight into Azure, but I imagine SSIS could at least invoke a Python script, or invoke a .bat file that invokes a python script?

Comment: @Manakin SSIS can do run command line program but for someone that knows neither technology, I find the cleaner you can make the separation of duties between programs, the easier it is going to be on them. I think about things with python that might trip them up like - is it installed on the box? user instance or system-wide install. Can we assume that the correct libraries, pandas/beautifulsoup4, have been pip'ped? Did they get 32 or 64 bit? etc. If the OP were a native python person, I'd probably advocate skipping CSV and just pypyodbc the data into the database.